# Software Updater terminates unexpectedly

Tags: updates, update-manager

I am currently facing the problem that Ubuntu Software Updater offers me to install some updates, but after hitting `install` the process terminates.
This started last week and first I thought that the updater would maybe install the updates in the background (I haven't got any crash reports).
The updates have not been installed and the list of available updates gets longer and longer. Currently 124 MB need to be installed, but the procedure is always the same:
I hit install and the window disappears silently.

I thought that insufficient memory could be the cause (Kernel Updates are also included), but I got 100 MB on Boot and 9 GB on Home of free space left and that should of course be enough.

Comment: Can you post the output (from a terminal) of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @bain That commands worked fine. It went through the entire procedure without errors and now after asking software updater to check for updates it says that everything is up-to-date. I guess it was just a GUI issue making it not work...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to mention what bain recommended. Sometime it happens that some issues are not solved by the Software Updater, so it crashes. This could be some python wrong calls or anything in between. But the solution in most of my cases are:

- Taking care of any updating stage issues

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Taking care of any installing/upgrading/dependencies stage issues

  ```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

Sometimes even `sudo apt-get -f install` is needed to force an install and fix some dependencies. It varies but they solve the issue most of the time, afterwards Software Updater, Software Center and even Synaptic install packages correctly.